# ASP.net mvc Jquery Tab work fine in IE but not in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, cross-browser

Im just cross-browser testing my website. It is developed in Asp.net mvc 3. Throughout development it was tested in Internet Explorer and it was perfect. Now testing in Firefox and Chrome I get totally different results.

The problem relates to our use of Jquery UI tabs. They show up fine in IE but done show at all (just show the ul list elements not converted to tabs). Any ideas why it would work fine in IE but not in the other two browsers.

This is my script references in the site.master:

```
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/themes/Redmond/jquery-ui.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-en-GB.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have just found that it has something to do with the jquerytools reference. I comment that out and it runs as it should across all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being the Jquery.Tools mixing up with the Jquery.UI script. Have sorted out.

Thanks